# Dynamic high chart not rendering in MVC C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Below code is not rendering the chart on UI
My dynamic data dataObject array values are
[8.0,9.5,17.5,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,15.5] and my ui code is below. I have tried in different ways but it is not working. I am working in HighCharts first time

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="min-width:310px; height:400px;margin:0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var dataObject = new Array();

    var PprofileId = 1;
    var PparamName = 'Motor RPM';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ThirdPartyDriveData/GetDriveDataByIdAndName',
        data: { profileId: PprofileId, paramName: PparamName },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            $.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
                debugger;
                if (item.Dataset != '' && item.Dataset >= 0) {
                    dataObject.push(' ' + item.Dataset);
                }
            });
            //alert(result);
            CreateChart(dataObject);
            //alert(response);
        },
        Error: function () { }

    });
 });

    function CreateChart(dataObject) {

    debugger;
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: dataObject
        }]
    });
   }
</script>
```

Can anyone please help me on this. what is my mistake here

Comment: Hi @Eswar reddy, Something is wrong with your data. Could you provide me with the `data` variable in the `success` function? The values from `dataObject` works fine, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wo18td0h/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to push data with `' '` here?

```
dataObject.push(' ' + item.Dataset);
```

I put `[8.0,9.5,17.5,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,15.5]` instead of `dataObject` in `CreateChart` function and it works.

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width:310px; height:400px;margin:0 auto"></div> 


<script type="text/javascript">

     CreateChart(null);
 

    function CreateChart(dataObject) {

    debugger;
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [8.0,9.5,17.5,18.9,18.9,18.9,18.9,15.5]
        }]
    });
   }
</script>
```